How can I swap an entity form for a given bundle?
I want to use a different form altogether from the defined edit form for a given bundle of an entity. I have found how to swap the form for every bundle of the entity here:
Override entity form handler
However I cannot figure out how to do this on a per-bundle basis. Does anyone have a method?

I remember looking for the same thing a while back and coming up empty. Looking at the code now (even in D11) there doesn't seem to be any hints that the entity form could be configurable per-bundle. You might have to make do with overriding the form class completely, and using the buildForm method to dispatch to other classes based on the bundle of the form object

Thanks Clive, I've been working at exactly that, but not finding nice solutions. I can get the form to load, but trying to use any submit handlers causes core form errors. I'll keep plugging away!

I was overthinking it. It  was actually quite simple.

Isn't that always the way :) It would still be nice to have proper support for this, feels like it wouldn't take much to implement. A feature request may be brewing...

Yeah. From a processing point, the original form is still generated before being swapped, so it's not a perfect solution, but it works very well for the time being.

Yes, it's not perfect. You can't be sure the form workflow will be the same in future Drupal versions. Better file a feature request, and in the meantime, add your custom class as an extra form mode and use it exclusively for the bundle, for example with hook_entity_form_mode_alter.

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3491100

I've found a solution, and it was surprisingly simple. The answer was to swap out the entire form in a hook form alter implementation.
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MODULE_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id = [BUNDLE FORM ID]) {
    $form_entity = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
    $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(FormClassToUseInstead::class, $form_entity);
  }
}

This works with ajax, and my form values are saving correctly.
-- Edit --
I'll note, this isn't ideal, as the original form is built before being swapped out. Ideally, core will provide a method of overriding the form by bundle. I have opened a feature request here:
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3491100
